# What is the purpose of this disconnected copper pipe next to my baseboard heating?

Tags: baseboard, water-circulating-heating

I just purchased a home and there is a disconnected copper pipe next to the baseboard heater in the garage. It is connected to the water system, although the connection is currently closed, water started flowing when I opened it.

When I turn up the thermostat on the wall, I do feel heat coming from the baseboard heater.

I am thinking it is/used to be part of the heater, but I'm not sure why its disconnected.
[image: Copper Pipe Next to heater]

Comment: If that heater is electric, I would be moving any water pipes far away.  Imagine pipe was used for something that was taken away, but left the pipe hanging around.

Comment: It's gas powered I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Water supply to a (former) garage fridge.

The location next to the baseboard is (presumably) a matter of where it was easy to run, not indicative of an association of the two systems. That size tubing is very common for fridge water dispensers and ice makers, pretty much unheard of in heating systems, unless heating oil (or refrigerant) comes out of it.

Refrigerators in garages, on the other hand, are dead common, and frequently they gravitate towards being "the drinks fridge" so an icemaker and/or water dispenser make a great deal of sense.

Can't know for certain, of course, but I'll stand by 99.9972% chance it's unrelated to heating system.

Comment: Did you know that 89.2344% of internet statistics are made up on the spot? :D

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the answer. A fridge would fit in this spot and now that I look, there is an empty outlet around fridge height. What do you think about having a fridge next to the baseboard heater? This is something I might want to put in myself.